# RadMenu Hide Top level Menu Items code behind

Tags: telerik, radmenu

I have a top level menu item with no submenu items that I like to hide in the code behind.

On Page_Load, I have the following but does not seem to hide the menu item

```
RadMenu1.FindItemByText("UserPage").Remove();
```

Comment: Why not use Hide instead of Remove?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know my post is a little late, but perhaps this can help others.

```
Dim Raditem As RadMenuItem = RadMenu1.FindItemByText("UserPage")
If Not Raditem Is Nothing Then
    Raditem.Visible = False
End If
```